# MQTT packet Encryption/Decryption API in Paho C library

Tags: mqtt, paho

[image]

I am using Paho MQTT C code, In MQTTClient_publish.c I enabled the all TLS/SSL related thing in code level and communication done working fine. But am not able to find the which API is encrypting packet.

[image]

Comment: Please do NOT post images of code they are really hard to read and impossible to search, post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the code you have posted is doing any encrypting/decrypting of the MQTT packets.

The Paho client code sets up a TLS connection to the broker as part of opening the socket using the openssl library. This socket has the same read/write functions as a normal socket and the paho library uses these to either pass outgoing packets or read incoming packets from the socket. The openssl socket wrapper deals with all the encryption/decryption.

If you want more detail feel free to read the Paho source code.

Comment: Thanks for reply hardillb,By using wire shark,with port number 1883 I see the data (hello world)  with out enabling the TLS/SSL. when  TLS/SSL enabled in code  and  port number 8883 am not able to see the data and it is showing the encrypted data . Is there any api for encrypt Mqtt packet in paho cilent.

Comment: You've just answered your own question. If you want encrypted packets use TLS

Comment: could please tell me, how to check through api level packet encryption in paho mqtt client code.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. If you enable TLS then the link between the client and the broker will be encrypted.